# Which Marvel characters have STIs?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics

In [Spider Man Reign](https://www.wired.com/2007/02/spidermans_radi/), Peter Parker passes radioactive semen into Mary Jane, which caused Mary Jane to get cancer and die. To my mind, this qualifies as a sexually transmitted disease.

> "Oh God, I’m sorry! The doctors didn’t understand how it happened! How
>   you had been poisoned by radioactivity! How your body slowly became
>   riddled with cancer! I did. I was… I am filled with radioactive blood.
>   And not just blood. ***Every fluid. Touching me… loving me… Loving me
>   killed you!"***

**Are there any other Marvel characters that have been shown to have sexually transmitted infections?**

Comment: This seems like quite a long question. And by long I mean it could have quite a few answers. Although I wouldn't know.

Comment: In spite of my above comment, I don't think this question is "too broad" as it has a narrow enough scope to be on-topic. The answer might be a bit 'list-y' but even then I doubt it will be longer than many questions we've left open on the site.

Comment: There's a handful of moderately prominent DC characters with AIDS and HIV (including a couple of the current lineup of the Teen Titans). A cursory search reveals no **Marvel** superheroes, only minor non-powered characters.

Comment: @edlothiad - Given that it's not trivially searchable, I'm happy to leave this open. It's clearly not going to be a long list.

Comment: There are a few, a Jim something is one I found. But yes, this seems like an intriguing question

Comment: Difference between STI and STD would be applicable here
https://www.stdcheck.com/blog/std-vs-sti-whats-the-difference/

Comment: What i'd like to know is why his fluids are radioactive. it's not like that's like a virus that spreads. the tiny amount from the spiderbite should be long washed out of his system.

Comment: @ths that's what you find hard to believe, and not how it gave him superpowers?

Comment: "To my mind, this qualifies as a sexually transmitted disease." No, it doesn't. The cancer was caused by radiation, not directly transmitted via sex. You're stretching the definition way beyond breaking point here.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist to be fair... so it the comic.

Comment: According to Chuck Austen, [Mutants can't contact AIDS](http://www.cbr.com/things-that-turned-out-bad-mutants-cant-get-aids/), but the other diseases are not ruled out

Comment: @AnthonyGrist You could also call them Sexually Transmissible Infections/Diseases.

You can get HIV from blood contamination but it is still considered an STI.

Comment: Does his web also give cancer?

Comment: @clint Eastwood: It's not generated from his body, so that would probably be a separate issue.

Comment: If Marvel characters means just characters in comics Marvel published, then the MAX books would be a good place to look - especially Ennis' *Punisher* run. I would not be surprised if a cop or a criminal he focused on for one or two storylines didn't have some sort of STI.

Answer (score 3):

James Wilson is said to have HIV/AIDS. Marvel Comics

> Incredible Hulk #388. In this story it is stated that Jim Wilson was
>   suffering from HIV/AIDS

There are a bunch more on this site but from different comic studios.
https://www.stdcheck.com/blog/comic-book-superheroes-hiv-immune-stds/